# How to check if a given app is installed on internal or external storage

Tags: android

I am trying to get the location of app by passing package name to check if its installed on internal or external storage. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

U can check this code and see whether we have installed on internal or external storage

(Note: u can use it in oncreate or any where)

```
ApplicationInfo io = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();

if(io.sourceDir.startsWith("/data/")) {
Toast.makeText(this,"your app is in internal storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//application is installed in internal memory
} else if(io.sourceDir.startsWith("/mnt/") || io.sourceDir.startsWith("/sdcard/")) {
Toast.makeText(this,"your app is in external storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//application is installed in sdcard(external memory)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check this out 


 public class Example extends Activity
        {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                //Put the package name here...
                boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.packagename");  
                if(installed)
                {
                //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.packagename");
            startActivity(LaunchIntent);


                          System.out.println("App already installed om your phone");


                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("App is not installed om your phone");
                }
            }
            private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri)
            {
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                boolean app_installed = false;
                try
                {
                       pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                       app_installed = true;
                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
                {
                       app_installed = false;
                }
                return app_installed ;
        }
        }
```

Comment: I know I can check that, but as I said above I wanted to know the location of the app , either its installed on SDcard or internal memory. That's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
if ((applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 0) {
    // installed on sdcard
}
```